# 'int' object is not subscriptable. Tuple error

Tags: python, list, pygame, tuples

How do I resolve the issue in my code, that generates a `TypeError`?

```py
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        self.x = 607
        self.y = 420
        self.pos = [(self.x, self.y)]

    def movement(self, x, y):
        self.x += x
        self.y += y
        self.pos = [self.x, self.y]

    def draw(self):
        for tup in self.pos:
            if (tup[0] == self.x) and (tup[1] == self.y):
                pygame.draw.circle(self.board.window, (255, 255, 0), (self.x, self.y), 8)

    def update(self):
        pygame.display.update()
```

> ```non
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/Users/fotio_000/PycharmProjects/Pacman/main.py", line 4, in <module>
>    board = Board()
>    File "C:\Users\fotio_000\PycharmProjects\Pacman\Game.py", line 32, in __init__
>    self.all_events()
>    File "C:\Users\fotio_000\PycharmProjects\Pacman\Game.py", line 38, in all_events
>    self.draw()
>    File "C:\Users\fotio_000\PycharmProjects\Pacman\Game.py", line 65, in draw
>    self.player.draw()
>    File "C:\Users\fotio_000\PycharmProjects\Pacman\Player.py", line 18, in draw
>    if (tup[0] == self.x) and (tup[1] == self.y):
> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
> ```

Comment: Why do you need multiple positions for the object player?

Comment: Note to reviewers.  This question should not be closed.  The implied question is clear enough to produce an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need multiple positions for the object player?

Int the constrictor `self.pos` is a list of tuples:

> ```py
> self.pos = [(self.x, self.y)]
> ```

but when you change it in `movement` it is a single positions with 2 coordinates stored in a list:

> ```py
> self.pos = [self.x, self.y]
> ```

That is what causes the error. Changing the later to `self.pos = [(self.x, self.y)]` would solve the issue, but ...

Since you want to draw a circle at the position (`self.x`, `self.y`) there is no need to compare the position(s) in the list to (`self.x`, `self.y`). Note, (`self.x`, `self.y`) is always stored in the list, so why do you try to verify that?
Just draw the circle at (`self.x`, `self.y`). e.g.:

```py
class Player(object):

    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.board.window, (255, 255, 0), (self.x, self.y), 8)
```